# multiline sql query in python with comments

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x

If we want to break long sql query in multiple lines we can do:

```
data = db_fetchquery(f"""SELECT price
                    FROM car WHERE make_year = '{make_year}'
                    AND model = '{model}'""")
```

Now, this is just a short example in real am having 16 and with nested where clause so I wan to comment each conditions so its easy to recall. just like:

```
data = db_fetchquery(f"""SELECT price #selecting price
                    FROM car WHERE make_year > '{make_year}' #where make_year > the requested make_year
                    AND model = '{model}'""") #specific model
```

Comment: First of all, your code is vulnerable to SQL injection vulnerabilities. Secondly, you can concatenate string literals with just putting them one after the other.

Comment: you can use `--`  instead of `#` to comment something in sql

Comment: Can also use /* Comments.. */ for more then one line

Comment: # is not a valid comment identifier in any SQL flavor I'm aware of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in sql language , one-line comments start with `--`
and multiple line comments using `/* <comment> */`
so :

```
data = db_fetchquery(f"""SELECT price /* selecting price */
                    FROM car WHERE make_year > '{make_year}' /*where make_year > the requested make_year */
                    AND model = '{model}'""") #specific model
```